# ADsOpenObject password encrypted?

Tags: c++, windows, ldap

I'm getting some details from Active Directory via LDAP url, for this
ADsOpenObject in msdn library:

```
hRes = ADsOpenObject(pwszBindingString, pwszUSER, pwszPASS, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION,IID_IADs, (void**)&iads );
```

I'm having doubt about whether the given password will be encrypted or not while connecting  the Domain Controller

Answer (score 3):

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says

> Caution  If a user name and password are specified without specifying authentication flags, the user name and password are transmitted over the network in plaintext, which is a security risk. Do not specify a user name and password without specifying authentication flags.

You are using the `ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION` flag from the [`ADS_AUTHENTICATION_ENUM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which means:

> Requests secure authentication. When this flag is set, the WinNT provider uses NT LAN Manager (NTLM) to authenticate the client. Active Directory will use Kerberos, and possibly NTLM, to authenticate the client. When the user name and password are NULL, ADSI binds to the object using the security context of the calling thread, which is either the security context of the user account under which the application is running or of the client user account that the calling thread represents.

Both NTLM and Kerberos are protocols that "encrypt" the password.  If you want the username encrypted as well, then you need SSL (which requires that a certificate server is setup for the domain).

You can always use a packet sniffer to verify that the information is encrypted.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not clear with the flag, should i specify any specific flags else any flags in ADS_AUTHENTICATION_ENUM for encrypted username, password in ldap connection

Comment: @RaviKumar I edited the answer with a description of the `ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION` flag, and interpreted it for you.

Comment: @Sean Hall I do not have the time to "sniff" right now, this is a collateral project I choose to believe!